# Symfony2 : form element with two id attributes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, entity

I was trying to build an embedded form with Symfony2/Twig in which I wanted to display the id of the mapped entity for each line on the form.
I was doing this :

```
{% for p in form.products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{p.vars.data.id}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

which is very simple ... but nothing was printed.
I tried the following :

```
{% for p in form.products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{dump(p.vars)}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And the result was unexpected :

```
array:27 [▼   "value" => ItemProduct {#857 ▼
    -id: null
    #enabled: false
    #commission: 0.0
    #support: 1
    -quantity: 0
    -id: 1   }
```

Two `id` attributes for the element. I didn't know it was even possible and I don't understand how this can happen, my code is extremly simple and I never encountered such issues before even with far more complex embedded forms.

Here is the rest of my code :

ItemProductType

```
class ItemProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder -> add ( 'artist_commission' , 'text' );
    }
    // ...
}
```

ItemProductsType

```
class ItemProductsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('products', 'collection', array('type' => new ItemProductType()));
}
```

ItemProduct

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="item_products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="APIBundle\Entity\ItemProductRepository")
 */
class ItemProduct extends Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $enabled;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    protected $commission;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $support;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally found what was wrong (writing the question probably made me have a new look on my code).

My `ItemProduct` inherits a `Product` class which has its own `id` attribute. Since there are two distinct tables and the `id` attribute is not merged properly Symfony makes the two different `id` attributes visible.
As only one of them was actually linked to the data, the other was null.

Even if the problem is solved and revealed larger issues in my code I am still interested in explanation about this behaviour and how it is possible to make to attributes with the same name coexist in an entity.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, this will mark this question as resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer